# My code wont execute properly, I'm using C, I,'m getting no errors. I may have a misunderstanding of the operations

Tags: c, arrays, string

Please excuse me, i'm returning to the programming world after being out of school and practice for 3 years and even then I only took one programming class, so i'm trying to relearn C programming while taking this algorithms class. Thank you for any help you can provide and please let me know if you need more information. I will be working to hopefully crack this on my own and will take it down if I get it.

Here is my code, it is just the start of a whole program and i'm already stumped. I'm trying to get it to accept an amount of test cases(no use at this part), request a number of words to take in and put it in a 2D array, and then take in 7 tiles available, then print the seven tiles. 
What it does is in an image i've provided, but if you cant see it. It stores the amount of words into the 2D array, but wont accept input for the 7 tiles and prints the last entry in the 2D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int MAX_WORD_LENGTH;

int main(){

    srand(time(0));
    int n, c, i, j;
    char wordList[n][MAX_WORD_LENGTH], tileList[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    char words;

    //Ask the user for number of input cases.
    printf("Please enter a number 1-20.\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Please enter the amount of words to check.\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    //prompt user to enter words from dictionary.
    printf("Please enter your words no more than 7 characters, one at a time, followed by 'ENTER'.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        scanf("%s\n", wordList[i]);


    printf("What seven tiles do you have available? Please use all caps.\n");
    scanf("%s", tileList);
    printf("%s\n", tileList);

    return 0;

}
```

[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jis8m.png)

Comment: [Edit] to include your program's output _as text_, not an image.  Just copy and paste it from the console window.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you have no *errors*. To fix that, compile with `-Werror`.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `n` when`wordList` is declared?

Comment: Thank you dbush for giving me the hint instead of just telling me. What a silly mistake on my end. So if im understanding the logic right, because 'n' was initialized before wordList, but wasnt given a value until after, C doesnt go back and replace all instances of 'n' with its new value? so wordList has what ever trash data was stored in the memory spot of 'n' before it was initialized? which is why main returns the -107...0 value?